# Counting the Number of MSB Zeros

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Is there a logical way to count number of most significant zeros?

For example

```
5 leading zeros                    5
00000100 -> combinational logic -> 00000101
1 leading zero                     1
01000000 -> combinational logic -> 00000001
0 leading zeros                    0
11111000 -> combinational logic -> 00000000
```

Edit: Using gates

Comment: You could count them, right? So yes, there is a way.

Comment: Well I mean yes, I'm asking for a way to implement the logic in gates, just wondering if there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: Standard? No. But it is pretty easy even to build a truth table for it, given most of the rows will be don't-cares. And the output is 3 (well, 4) bits only.

Comment: Just do a truth table with 8 bits to 3 bits. You will eventually find the logical equation.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to extrapolate this out to 32 bits.

Comment: Well start with, say, eight bits, show your work in your question and someone will respond with improvements, etc.

Comment: You might be able to use the 8-bit devices and come up with a solution based on them for 32 bit.

Comment: Is this to be synthesized in VHDL/Verilog?

Comment: yes the end goal is for synthesis

Comment: shift register with counter if 0.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat It's not combinatorial.

Comment: You might also look for "barrel shifter with automatic normalization" (which I often used in the ADSP21xx series of parts and should have what you require within it) and also add the keyword "cascadable" if you are interested in breaking this into subsections to reach 32 bits. There's a lot of free IP out there to examine, I suspect. Or just skip the "barrel shifter" bit and look for automatic normalization.

Comment: "priority encoder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative, more classical, solution.

[image]

[Simulator.IO](https://simulator.io/board/07pAZ5szSK/1)

Note you can actually reduce this by one OR gate since the term "6 OR 7" is used on both Bit 1 and Bit 2 of the encoder.

Comment: @jackana3 you are welcome. It was a fun challenge ;)

Comment: BTW some creditshould also go to @supercat. The above is basically what he was saying too, I think...

Comment: I started to implement supercats but I had a little trouble without a visual. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to produce a "one-hot" output for the least significant bit which is preceded by all "zeroes" [there will only be one such bit].  Each bit of the count will then be the "or" of half the one-hot outputs.  For example, in an 8-bit system one could get a three-bit count of leading bits by ORing together one-hot outputs 0, 2, 4, and 6 for the LSB of the count, one-hot outputs 0, 1, 4, and 5 for the middle bit of the count, and outputs 0, 1, 2, and 3 for the MSB of the count.

If the number of bits is large, it may make sense to cascade smaller OR gates rather than giant ones of size N/2.  If this is done, smaller gates may be shared over multiple terms.  For example, if N is 16, the OR gate which is used to combine one-hots 0, 1, 2, and 3 could be combined with the one for one-hots 8, 9, 10, and 11 to produce bit 2 of the count, and with one-hots 4, 5, 6, and 7 to produce bit 3 of the count.

Answer (score 0):

A whole bunch of adders is reasonably scaleable.

This uses the fairly typical bit counter adder structure with the addition of the roll through sequence filtering logic OR gates on the front.

[image]

[Simulator.IO](http://simulator.io/board/Wea9Wa9cvm/2)

Comment: That seems a bit overcomplicated.  For an n-bit number, if one generates a one-hot output for the last leading zero, one simply needs for each bit of the result an n/2-input "or" gate.

Comment: @supercat perhaps you can show that as an answer.

Comment: @supercat actually when you break it down it is fairly simple.